# Square and two types of rectangles

Tags: combinatorics, tiling, rectangles

A $60\times 60$ square $S$ is divided into $2\times 5$ rectangles. Prove that no matter how this is done there is a way to divide $S$ into $1\times 3$ rectangles so that each of the above $2\times 5$  rectangles contains one of the $1\times 3$ rectangles.

A bashy idea (which I cannot actually complete) is to show that we can always remove one-by-one connected figures of $30$ squares, composed of three $2\times 5$ rectangles, so that the resulting figure remains connected; and then check that each such figure of $30$ squares can be tiled with a $1\times 3$ rectangles.

Any idea of something smarter? (Or if not, at least a fast way to complete the details of the above strategy?) Any help appreciated!

Comment: Remove one-by-one connected figures of $30$ square doesn't actually work, here's a  [counter example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekeRb.png)

Comment: @Asher2211 There are certainly arrangements of three $2\times 5$ rectangles that can't be tiled, but that doesn't mean you will be forced to remove such an arrangement.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Each $2\times 5$ rectangle contains $1\times 3$ rectangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1865160/318073).